# Create categorical variable from previous columns in R

Tags: r, if-statement, statistics, categories

I have been trying to create a new categorical variable from previous binary variables. All the binary variables I'm trying to include (cough, fever, etc...) have values of either '1' or '0'.
This is the code I've been trying:

```
symptoms<-ifelse(cough==1,"cough",ifelse(fever==1,"fever",ifelse(diarrhea==1,"diarrhea",ifelse(dispnea==1,"dispnea",ifelse(neurologic==1,"neurologic",ifelse(otherSymp==1,"other symtomes", NA))))))
```

The problem is that the output results in only 4 categories, not 6.

I know this is a basic question, sorry and thank you in advance.

Comment: `names(df)[max.col(df)]` where `df <- data.frame(cough, fever, diarrhea, dispnea, neurologic, otherSymp)`

Comment: I would use `case_when` function from `dplyr`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, [`case_when`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) is a helpful alternative to many nested `ifelse` calls:

```r
library(dplyr)

# Create sample dataset
df <- data.frame(cough = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
                 fever = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
                 diarrhea = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
                 dyspnea = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
                 neurologic = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                 otherSymp = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0))

# Create categorical variable
df |> mutate(symptom = case_when(cough == 1 ~ "cough",
                                 fever == 1 ~ "fever",
                                 diarrhea == 1 ~ "diarrhea",
                                 dyspnea == 1 ~ "dyspnea",
                                 neurologic == 1 ~ "neurologic",
                                 otherSymp == 1 ~ "other",
                                 TRUE ~ "none"))
```

Output

```r
#>   cough fever diarrhea dyspnea neurologic otherSymp    symptom
#> 1     1     0        0       0          0         0      cough
#> 2     0     1        0       0          0         0      fever
#> 3     0     0        1       0          0         0   diarrhea
#> 4     0     0        0       1          0         0    dyspnea
#> 5     0     0        0       0          1         0 neurologic
#> 6     0     0        0       0          0         1      other
#> 7     0     0        0       0          0         0       none
#> 8     1     1        1       1          0         0      cough
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

However, this is a very basic solution, which assumes that you can't have more than one symptom (unreasonable) - if you have more than one, `symptom` will only mention the first.